# The if/else method doesn't running properly

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to make a method, which show `vbcim` as 0 if value is not in the `versenyzok.txt`, and show the real value if value is found. 
Something is misunderstood by me, and the `Feltolt` method doesn't running properly.

It should list the results from the text file. If the 4th value is not found set it as 0, and if its found list it as well

```
  package vizsgamintaa;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    //import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    //import java.util.logging.Level;
    //import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class VizsgaMintaA {

        static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
       static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
            ArrayList<Versenyzo> versenyzok = new ArrayList<>();
            Feltolt(versenyzok);
            Kiir(versenyzok);
        }
        private static void Feltolt(ArrayList<Versenyzo> versenyzok) throws ParseException{
        Versenyzo v;
        File f = new File("versenyzok.txt");
        try {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(f, "iso-8859-2");
                while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    String sor = scan.nextLine();
                    String[] adatok = sor.split(";");
                    if (adatok.length == 3) {
                       v = new Versenyzo();
                       v.nev = adatok[0];
                        v.szuletes = df.parse(adatok[1]);
                         v.csapat = adatok[2];
                         if (adatok[3].length()==0 )  {

                            v.vbcim = 0; 
                        } 
                         else {
                            v.vbcim = Integer.parseInt(adatok[3]);
                        }
                    } else {
                         v = new Versenyzo (adatok[0],df.parse(adatok[1]),adatok[2],Integer.parseInt(adatok[3]));
                    }
                    versenyzok.add(v);

                    }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Nincs meg a fájl.");
            }

        }

        public static void Kiir(ArrayList<Versenyzo>versenyzok){
        for (Versenyzo f : versenyzok){
            System.out.println(f.toString());
        }
        }
    }
       class Versenyzo {

           String nev,csapat;
           Date szuletes;
           int vbcim;
           SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");

            @Override
       public String toString(){
       return "Versenyzo:" +nev + "Született:" + df.format(szuletes)+"Csapata:"+ csapat + "Vb címek:" + vbcim; 
       }
       public Versenyzo(String nev, Date szuletes, String csapat, int vbcim) {
           this.nev = nev;
           this.szuletes = szuletes;
           this.csapat = csapat;
           this.vbcim = vbcim;

       }
       public Versenyzo(){
       }
    }
```

The

```
else {     
       v = new Versenyzo (adatok[0],df.parse(adatok[1]),adatok[2],Integer.parseInt(adatok[3]));
  }
```

part is some way not works. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` it says.

Comment: what exactly is not  running properly? can you give us expected and actual results?

Comment: Updated. I just need the way to give `vbcim` result 0 if value is not found in the text file, and the exact value if value can be found in the text file.

Comment: It should list the results from the text file. If the 4th value is not found set it as 0, and if its found list it as well.

Comment: you need to learn about array indexing, first you have a `if (adatok.length == 3)` condition then you access the 4th element of the array within that code block and in the `else` block you access elements of the array without having any ideas what the size of the array is it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you check:

```
if (adatok.length == 3)
```

and in the `else` part you take for granted that the `length` is at least `4`, but it seems that isn't. 
Maybe it is less than `2`, so you get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to access `adatok[3]`.
 
You should change to something like this:

```
if (adatok.length == 3) {
    //......
} else if (adatok.length > 3) {
    //......
} else {
    //......
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have sit for two days on this problem. :)